# What is this diamond-shaped voltage source symbol, and how can I solve this puzzle?

Tags: circuit-analysis

One of my friends sent me this question but I have never seen anything like that, anyone knows what is it or how can I solve it? Question asks: what's the value of alpha and calculate the power of current source using alpha?

Also what's that thing in the middle?

[image]

Comment: The ideal source in the center is a current dependent voltage source. The voltage produced by it is proportional to the current i-delta.

Comment: So delta is 400 ? (6v/15ma) and power is 90mW ? Also if I understand it right right part is some kind of current meter ?

Comment: The question title is among the worst I've seen, but I'm stumped as to what it _should_ be.

Comment: @JYelton Yeah sorry about that , language differences making it really problematic

Comment: Is your friend your teacher, by any chance?

Comment: Revisiting this, I have changed the title to be more applicable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing in the middle is a dependent voltage source. It is a voltage source that has a variable voltage, the value of which depends on the given formula.

Now on to solving this puzzle... (it really is much more of a puzzle than a circuit)

The 6 V independent source *forces* the voltage between the two nodes to be 6 V.

This means that the voltage across the dependent source must also be 6 V. As the +/- signs are reversed, this means that \$\alpha i_\Delta = -6\text{ V}\$. But we know that \$i_\Delta = -15\text{ mA}\$ looking at the current through the current source.

Plugging in \$i_\Delta\$ into the first equation, we get

$$\alpha\cdot(-15\text{ mA}) = -6\text{ V}$$

So

$$\alpha = 400\text{ Ω}$$

You can actually calculate the power of the current source without doing any of this, since \$P = IV\$ and you know both \$I\$ and \$V\$. Just multiply 6 V times 15 mA and you get 90 mW.

Comment: Okay thanks for answer , I have never seen anything like that before . Also I want to be clear , current source's power is 90mW and right part is some kind of current meter ?

Comment: @Mordecai - All three of the circuit elements here are sources. Circular ones are *independent* sources, meaning the value is constant, and diamond ones are *dependent* sources, meaning the value changes based on the given formula. If the source has + - in it, it is a voltage source, whereas if it has an arrow it is a current source. In summary, the right part is an independent current source.

Comment: The part of this circuit that could be called a current meter is the little blue arrow on the top next to \$i_\Delta\$.

Comment: I researched the topic but whole idea seem like "imaginary" or "ideal" . You can't use this in real life circuits , can you ?

Comment: @Mordecai, you can't put one (ideal) voltage source in parallel with another in a real circuit. But there are lots of devices (transistors, for example) that are modeled with dependent sources.

Comment: So it's just a basic schematic of more complicated circuit ? Like you can show a box which says " feedback " or you can draw the whole circuit feedback circuit